# Can't reach localhost via browser.Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new at RoR. 
I've just installed RoR on my local computer,but I can't open localhost page with it. 
After **rails s** command it showed to me this :

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
A server is already running. Check /home/roma/Templates/first_app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

What could be a problem?

Comment: did you check `/home/roma/Templates/first_app/tmp/pids/server.pid`?

Comment: Yes.It contain only 6278 number.

Comment: Hm.Only restart helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the same app is already running. If not, simply delete the file located at /home/roma/Templates/first_app/tmp/pids/server.pid.

Answer (score 0):

run `kill -15 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid )` from inside your project, e.g:

```
cd /home/roma/Templates/first_app/
kill -15 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid )
```

That would kill the rails server running